If the Moon started emitting light, how would it affect human sleep/wake cycles?
I'm working on a sci-fi setting, and things start when the Moon starts emitting a unique type of light.
Things to note

The light being emitted by the Moon doesn't produce heat. Things are getting brighter, but not hotter, so please ignore any thermal effects of light when answering this question. It is identical to normal light in every other way except for the change in point 6.
The new moon, both quarter moons and full moon phases appear to last 3 days long. The Moon is still moving, so lunar cycle length, tides, and anything else affected by the movement of the Moon are unaffected, but anybody looking at the Moon would see the phase last for 3 days, regardless of how long it should appear to last.
The phase of the Moon affects the intensity of the light. At the new moon phase, the Moon doesn't emit any light (so for those three days, things are back to normal). As the lunar cycle progresses, the light gets brighter until the full moon phase, where the light emitted per square meter is the same as the light emitted per square meter from the Sun at noon. As the Moon passes the full moon phase and heads towards the new moon again, the light dims until the new moon phase, where there is no light again.
The Moon itself hasn't changed in any way apart from the fact it now emits light.
The Moon starts glowing during a full moon.
If it matters, the color of the light is silver, however, it affects sleep cycles as if it were light in the 460 nm/blue light range.
This story is set on Earth.

How would this new light affect a human's sleep/wake cycle?

For your #3 you indicate that the maximum light emitted per square meter from the moon is the same as the light emitted per square meter of the Sun at noon. Do you really mean that or do you mean something more like the light emitted per degree of solid angle or something like that? If the moon's brightness per square meter were the same as the sun's brightness per square meter, it would look far brighter than the sun due to the moon's proximity.

@Mathaddict: Ugh no not at all. The Moon is tiny compared to the Sun. There are enormously fewer square meters. If each square meter of the Moon emitted as much light as each square meter of the Sun the total light would be only about 6 times more than the light which comes from the ordinary full Moon, or about 2.5 EV steps. (Think of how many square meters of Moon surface fit in a solid angle of 0.2 square degrees compared to how many square meters of Sun surface fit in the same solid angle.)

@AlexP I was envisioning it to be as bright as the Sun, not dimmer or brighter. But saying as bright as the sun would be confusing, since the moon is much smaller but much closer. If I have described it poorly, then how about the light from the moon has the same intensity as the Sun, despite the fact it is much closer and much smaller. So looking at the moon during the full Moon would have the same effects as looking at the sun, it would illuminate the earth as much as the Sun does, etc. Does that make things more clear?

If it's not already been mentioned, for future reference: rather than posting a new version of a question, it's better to edit the old version until it's passed muster for reopening.

Should also be remembered that the moon is also visible during the day for most of the month so it won't just be impacting people during the night. https://www.livescience.com/why-moon-visible-daytime

@JoeW That's a good point. Since during the full moon it's similar to a 72 hour noon in some aspects, with constant exposure to the light most disruptive to sleep. Even people who could close curtains, stay away from a window, etc would be affected by the light all day, so that would have some affect at night. But how much will that impact their sleep/wake cycle?

Millions of people sleep routinely in cities with plenty of lights at night. They sleep decently just by ensuring that their curtains are closed shut.
Even those sleeping in the countryside have means to limit the amount of external light seeping in their dwellings.
The amount of people sleeping en plen air is very limited.
Therefore your new light casting moon would have little to no effect.

Millions of people live in cities close to the Arctic Circle, for example Reykjavík in Iceland, or Saint Petersburg in Russia, or Oslo in Norway, or Helsinki in Finland, where in summer it never gets really dark at night. They sleep just fine, due to this marvellous inventions of curtains.

@AlexP What about people who don't have curtains? Or other ways of keeping the light out at night? How would the sleep/wake cycle of people who had to have at least some exposure to outside when they wanted to sleep, so would affected by light much brighter than what a normal night would be?

@beautyandnotthebeast: I wouldn't know; I actually like to take a nap outside in summer afternoons when I'm on holiday, but maybe other people are different. (And anyway, everybody can stick their head under a sheet if they don't have curtains.) Remember that many people in this world work night shifts regularly and sleep during the day.

And if they don't have sheets, they can use a straw hat, an animal hide, or a pile of leaves.  Even the most impoverished/low-tech people in the world will be able to figure out something to cover their faces with.

@AlexP Okay, so some people can go inside. But what about the full moon, as  it's similar to a 72 hour noon in some aspects, with constant exposure to the light most disruptive to sleep. Even people who could close curtains, stay away from a window, etc would be affected by the light all day, so that would have some affect at night. But how much will that impact their sleep/wake cycle?

Humans could sleep fine, but there could be indirect consequences.
People sleep in homes which make regulating light in the home to sleep pretty easy... but the plants and animals that we rely on may be another story.  Plants base their glucose usage at night on how much sunlight they've received during the day to try to predict how long the night will be.  Plants try to use daylight to focus on glucose production and nighttime to focus on growth; so, if the moon is bright enough to make the plants think it is daytime, but not imparting the thermal energy of the sun to assist in photosynthesis, then  plants will waste more time trying to produce energy from light that it can not use and it will spend less time trying to grow in the dark.  Furthermore, many species of nocturnal pollinators may not be able to do their jobs under such bright moon light.  Overall this things will create a net reduction in plant growth and germination which will drive many animals, including humans, to famine.
Effects of Decreased Food Supply on Sleep
This will not be a universal problem since global food shortages don't affect the whole world equally like everyone has to cut back their eating a bit and everything is fine. In practice, countries with higher Per Capita GDPs like Norway, USA, Luxemburg, etc. will just buy up the differance, have enough food to be fine, and continue to sleep normally other than perhaps the minor anxiety issue that a slightly tighter budget might cause. That said, some of these populations may actually sleep better since overeating can lead to heartburn and hypertension that increases insomnia.
Middlish Per Capita GDP countries like China, Mexico, etc. will need to significantly cut back on food per person leading to mass malnutritional issues. Going to bed hungry elivates orexin levels, which can promote wakefulness and food-seeking behavior; so, in places where food is still available but scarce, it is common for people to suffer from a form of insomnia most often characterized by waking up frequently and having trouble going back to sleep.
Your poorest places like Niger, Chad, Uganda, etc. will be hit the worst because what excess food these places can grow will typically be sold out of country instead of being used to feed its own starving urban populations.  Such places are very vulnerable to mass starvation. Way beyond just not having enough food to sleep well, these places will see massive die offs and internal conflicts.  Cartels may rise up to seize control over the limited food supplies.  Those who have enough to eat will live in constant fear of being killed for their food... which is also not good for achieving a good night sleep, but at this point your society is faced with such grave troubles that worrying about getting your whole 8 hours of sleep is going to be the least of your problems.

That's a good point. Would hunger have a bigger impact on sleep than light levels?

@beautyandnotthebeast no and yes and no... global food shortages don't affect the whole world equally like everyone has to cut back their eating a bit and everything is fine.  In practice, countries with higher Per Capita GDPs like Norway, USA, Luxemburg, etc. will just buy up the differance.  They might feel a slight pinch in the pocketbook, but almost everyone is sleeping fine.  Middlish countries like China, Mexico, etc. will need to significantly cut back on food per person so they may not sleep so well going to bed hungry.

Ever poorer places like Niger, Chad, Uganda, etc. will be hit the worst. Such places are very vulnerable to mass starvation... so most of the people there will rest in peace...

So how big of an impact does hunger have on sleep?

@beautyandnotthebeast Moderate Food deprivation leads to insomnia.  I've added more details about in my answer, but giving exact figures is difficult since everyone responds to hunger a bit differently, and how much hunger will be different from one region to another.

Could also affect how certain species behave. Lions tend to be hungrier after full moons because the moonlight makes it easier for prey to spot them. Also, don't turtles use the lunar cycle to determine when to go ashore to lay eggs? Might also get species of wasp and bee active during the night?

@Anonymaton Yes, pretty much all wildlife will be affected to some degree or another, but the question was specific to the human sleep cycle.  Changes in pollinator behavior could also possibly worsen the famine, but changes in lion or sea turtle well being would probably not have a measurable effect.

@Anonymaton So it would have a much bigger impact on animals than humans then? Directly at least.

@beautyandnotthebeast Yes, plants and nocturnal animals would be the most adversely affected.  Animals that live in any sort of burrows would mostly just be affected by decreased food supplies.

@Nosajimiki So any country that has a stable economy and has a society that doesn't collapse will ultimately be fine.

@beautyandnotthebeast Humanity as a whole would adapt, and many civilizations would would make it through without any major consequences, yes.
